# Format URL in powershell to contain a $ sign

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to have a URL stored in a variable in powershell, but the issue comes to the correct formating.

For example I need to format this URL

```
https://graph.windows.net/mytenantname/users?$top=999?api-version=1.6
```

But i need to replace mytenantname with a variable

```
"https://graph.windows.net/$mytenantname/users?$top=999?api-verion=1.6"
```

but doing this i can't keep the `$top` as PowerShell treats is as a variable too....

Comment: use escape sequence

Comment: yes just figured it out i needed to use the backtick ` infront of the $sign on top thanks

Comment: You can also use single quotes for your string literal. Variables are not interpolated inside single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Use a backtick (`) on the dollar sign you want, and leave the variable dollar sign:

```
"https://graph.windows.net/$mytenantname/users?`$top=999?api-verion=1.6"
```